# does Xtemplate statements allow to match strings?

Tags: javascript, extjs, string-comparison

I've this question, I need to know if it is possible to have a string comparison operation on a parameter inside the XTemplate. My need is to know if there is a substring inside a string.
That's my code. I should need a statement checking if "L" is RIV_Filtro

```
var detailRivenditoreTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for="rivenditori">',
        '<div id="boxDettaglioRivenditori">',
        '<h1>{RIV_RagioneSociale}</h1>',
        '<div>',
        '{RIV_Indirizzo}',
        '<p>{RIV_CAP} - {RIV_Localita}, {RIV_Regione}</p>',
        '{RIV_Paese}',
        '</div>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

I guess it's not possible, but I just ask if somebody has already faced the problem.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean the contents of the {RIV_Filtro} field? Because then u can just use the if operator in the XTemplate.

Comment: yes, the content of `{RIV_Filtro}`. if `{RIV_Filtro}` is **"LC"** how can I know if **"L"** is a substring of `{RIV_Filtro}` ?

Comment: I've posted an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template functions something like this:

```
var detailRivenditoreTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for="rivenditori">',
        '<div id="boxDettaglioRivenditori">',
        '<h1>{RIV_RagioneSociale}</h1>',
        '<div>',
        '<tpl if="[this.checkFilter(RIV_Filtro)] &gt; -1">{RIV_Indirizzo}</tpl>',
        '<p>{RIV_CAP} - {RIV_Localita}, {RIV_Regione}</p>',
        '{RIV_Paese}',
        '</div>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>', {
        checkFilter: function(filter) {
            return filter.indexOf("L");
        }
     }
);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/KJfDE/

In the example, only if RIV_Filtro contains "L" RIV_Indirizzo will get shown.